# How to locate devices with Apache Cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, gps, position

I'm developing an Apache Cordova based APP for Android and iOS that sends push notification to devices near an event. I have to find a way to locate all devices when an event occurs, even if the app is closed or in background, and send the notification to all devices in a range.

I think there are two way:

1. my server can ask the position to all devices when an event occurs
2. a background service can push the position to my server every X minutes

Which is the simplest thing that I can do with Cordova and where I can find some examples?

Comment: This plugin track where a user is moving and uses therfore services/background-task to do so: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode . My plugin(https://github.com/blauharley/Cordova-Reminder) for android does not track a whole motion-sequence of a user but uses a service as well. So I just speak for myself but using services is easier than your first listed point. Another possibility is to use google's cloud messaging: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html  But when it comes to ios it gets more difficult for apple has got a strict cloud-messaging-system (APNs)

Comment: I already saw the cordova-plugin-background-mode, but I discarded it because its disclaimer: "The plugin focuses on enterprise-only distribution and may not compliant with all public store vendors.". Your plugin instead doesn't match my requirements. maybe should I write a native piece?

Comment: You are right but my intention was just to show you how easy you can make a piece of native code containing a service. When you want to make use of a plugin you just have to replace/extent little code of my plugin to make it send requests to your server ;)